# R - visNetwork - add animations to edges

Tags: r, vis.js, visnetwork

I would like to animate a message process by using a visNetwork.

For example, I have a network of persons who communicate with each other. In my example person 1 sends a message to person 2. After that, person 2 sends a message to person 3. I like to animate this process, like a small circle travelling from node 1 to node 2 and then from node 2 to node 3.  I found [this](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/507) regarding this problem, but this is JavaScript only. My result should look like [this](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4054499/8316376/6d3c2382-19ab-11e5-9660-26276a17ee9c.gif).

This is my network so far

```
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = 1:3)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges)
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Have you been able to get it to work outside of a shiny app?

Comment: No, but I don't need shiny. I have deleted the shiny part from my post.